# How to handle these variables in rsync exclude file?

Tags: backup, rsync, exclude

I have an ignore file for rsync but I can't figure out how to ignore this string of file names and the username:

```
backup/cpbackup/daily/username/homedir/mail/cur/1244452567.H511146P7355.dwhs45.dwhs.net,S=2161:2,

backup/cpbackup/daily/username/homedir/mail/cur/1244455430.H516330P14494.dwhs45.dwhs.net,S=4062:2,
```

I tried this:

```
backup/cpbackup/daily/*/homedir/mail/cur/*
```

and this:

```
*.*.dwhs45.dwhs.*
```

But of course that would be too easy.

Basically I just want to not transfer all the mail in the /cur/ directory for all users to the backups.

Answer (score 0):

`man rsync` has a whole section on INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERNS. In short, for the first case, you might first want to unanchor the match and make sure it's a directory, like so:

```
mail/cur/
```

No wildcards here, it will only ignore a *directory* called `cur` inside another directory called `mail`.